# How to get live updates via JSON to listview

Tags: android, json, web-services, listview

I couldn't find a way to get live updates via JSON to a listview.

My activity is requesting JSON data from a webpage and the code is:

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    static final String Li_nk = "LinkName:";
    static final String Image_name = "ImageName:";
    ListView list;
    public final static String AUTH = "authentication";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_image"; // Uri.decode("http://zeesms.info/android_app_images/Koala.jpg");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent i2 = getIntent();
        String wrd = i2.getStringExtra("entrd");
        Log.v("keyis", wrd);

        // if(wrd.equalsIgnoreCase("test")){
        JSONObject j2 = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("/webservice_search.php?keyword=" + wrd + "&format=json");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONArray jray = j2.getJSONArray("listings");
            for (int i = 0; i < jray.length(); i++) {
                Log.v("state", "json data being read");
                JSONObject j3 = jray.getJSONObject(i);
                String first = j3.getString("listing");
                Log.v("sublist", first);
                JSONObject j4 = j3.getJSONObject("listing");
                String sec = j4.getString("links");

                int maxLength = (sec.length() < 30) ? sec.length() : 27;
                sec.substring(0, maxLength);
                String cutsec = sec.substring(0, maxLength);
                Log.v("links are", cutsec);
                String img = j4.getString("image_name");
                Log.v("image name is ", img);
                // Uri
                // dimg=Uri.parse("http://zeesms.info/android_app_images/Koala.jpg");
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("Id", String.valueOf(i));
                map.put(Li_nk, cutsec);
                map.put(Image_name, j4.getString("image_name"));

                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, "http://zeesms.info/android_app_images/" + img);
                mylist.add(map);

            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            alertbox();
            Log.e("loG_tag", "Error parsing" + e.toString());
        }

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        this.list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click ListItem Number "
                // + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.riffre.com/"));
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        });
        LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mylist);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        // }
        /*
         * else{ alertbox(); }
         */

    }

    /*
     * public void register(View view) { Log.w("C2DM",
     * "start registration process"); Intent intent = new
     * Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
     * intent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new
     * Intent(), 0)); // Sender currently not used intent.putExtra("sender",
     * "nonsenses@gmail.com"); startService(intent); }
     * 
     * public void showRegistrationId(View view) { SharedPreferences prefs =
     * PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); String string =
     * prefs.getString(AUTH, "n/a"); Toast.makeText(this, string,
     * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Log.d("C2DM RegId", string);
     * 
     * }
     */
    public void alertbox() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Invalid Keyword,No Results found").setTitle("Alert").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                finish();

            }
        }).show();
    }
}
```

and I'm using a custom adapter with the code as follows:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view1, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.linkname); // merchnts name
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imagename); // address
        //TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id); // distance
       ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mClogo); // logo

        HashMap<String, String> jsn = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jsn = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
       title.setText(jsn.get(Second.Li_nk));
       artist.setText(jsn.get(Second.Image_name));
        //duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(jsn.get(Second.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

What I want is that the application updates the listview with data every minute or so.  Also the latest entry in the list should stay on top.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your JSON parsing code, that's probably your `try..catch` block in a separate function and not in `onCreate()`.

So can easily call that part every minute. let's say that function name `LoadData()` also add one more line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update adapter/list every time.

now in your onCreate(), write this code to call that function every one minute,

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //call the function
            LoadData();
            //also call the same runnable
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000);
```

Now for second problem, to add new data at top..

I am just getting one thing in mind right now to write a loop , ADD THIS TO IN YOUR FUNCTION BEFORE CALLING ADAPTER NOTIFY CHANGE,like

```
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylistTemp = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
     for(int i = mylist.size()-1 ; i >=0;i--)
     {
         mylistTemp.add(mylist.get(i));
     }
     mylist = mylistTemp;
```

Comment: I've implemented your code for the first part,now its updating constantly and the same data is being added to the list constantly,I've also added the notifydatasetchanged(),what could be causing this ?

Comment: what you mean bye `same data is being added to the list constantly` ?

Comment: the list is adding new views constantly of the same data ,like a never ending update

Comment: okay I've sorted that issue out,Although everytime it updates ,it scrolls back to the first position,is there anyway i can maintain the scroll position without using asynctask ??

Comment: yes sure everytime you notifyChange the adapter also use `listView.setSelection(positionToMove)`

Comment: what value should i add to positionToMove??

Comment: before updating the the value of list..means before fetching data..set value `positionToMove = yourArrayList.size()-1` so it will alsways..move to first record of the new data

Answer (score 2):

Well if your code above is working, you should be able to achieve your goal with the following steps:

- Extract your JSON-Loading code into an AsyncTask, which you can trigger every minute. ([AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115403/progressdialog-while-load-activity/10118869#10118869))
- Update your ListAdapter using the AsyncTask.

Comment: Well the code is working for sure,and I'm a noob to android,so could u provide an example similar to this instance or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible implementation of the onCreate() method, which will run an update-task every minute:

```
public class JSON_AndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private JSONLoaderTask mJSONLoaderTask;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    private Runnable mRefresher = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mJSONLoaderTask = new JSONLoaderTask(JSON_AndroidActivity.this, mArrayAdapter);
            mJSONLoaderTask.execute("");
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRefresher, 1000);
    }
}
```

And here is a hull implementation of a possible task, where you can do your heavy loading and update your adapter for the list:

```
public class JSONLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private final ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

    public JSONLoaderTask(Context pContext, ArrayAdapter<String> pArrayAdapter) {
        this.context = pContext;
        this.mArrayAdapter = pArrayAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         String result = getJSONStream();
        return result;
    }

    private String getJSONStream() {
        //load your string here
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // Update your ArrayAdapter
    }

}
```